# How to use JavaScript to stream parts of a file?

Tags: javascript

Given a really large, 3+ gig, binary file is there anyway that I could stream, from client to server, only portions of the file using JavaScript given that I know what byte range of the file that I want to receive?

I have a Ruby on Rails application that needs to grab specific portions of a file from the client. As one user has stated I could do this using Java.

Edit: After some reading it appears that HTML5 via slicing a file may be the best bet. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: You need more details about what you're attempting and what you've tried.  Are you trying to stream music? Video?  A slideshow?  A long book?

Comment: There's a library called AJAX Push Engine which can be used for streaming content. You might want to check it out. If you're planning to use JavaScript I suggest you use RingoJS for the back end. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where do you want the JavaScript to run? Classic ASP? Node.JS?

Comment: Is this streaming from client to server, or from server to client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is yes, assuming your web server supports it (which many do).

You can use the [`Range` HTTP header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35.2) to request only a part of the file (e.g. `Range: bytes=1000-2000`). Whether this works for you depends heavily on what you’re trying to accomplish — more information would help.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5123978/84745) for a discussion on using it.

Comment: This looks like what I would need, except I need to grab data from the client instead of the server. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really (at least not now, anyways). The file handling capabilities exposed to Javascript is not powerful enough to really do anything useful client-side when processing files to send back to the server (including things like only take part of a file). There are proposed w3c specs for better client-side file handling for javascript, but none of the major browsers implement it to a sufficient level to really handle this case quite yet.

I'm currently working on a project with similar needs, and the only options we found when we looked into this was to either use Flash, or to use Java. Since we are much more comfortable with Java than flash, we went that route.

We are currently using Groovy and the Griffon framework, as well as Grails for the server-side pieces. Griffon has been great because it frees us from the hassles of desktop vs. webstart vs. applet, and since it's built on Groovy, it can leverage the Swing DSLs so it is much less painless to write Swing.